# Regular expression to match 0 to 9 and selected symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression to match 0 to 9 (upto 10 digits) and `/-.` (0 to 2 max). Doesn't have to be all `.` or all `///`. Can be `/.-` or `.-.` or any combination of the three, but a maximum of 2 of those characters.

I'm trying to check if a date is in specified formats. The user can enter `1` or `10.02` etc. I'll split that value and use it later.

How do I do the regex for this? This is being done in Javascript.

I was trying `var pattern =/^([0-9([\/.-]{0,2})]{1,10})$/g;` until I gave up.

Edit:
`1 ->true`
`10.10 - true`
`10.12/2020 - true`
`/ -> false`
`.10.20 - false`

Comment: provide some example strings

Comment: Do you need a regular expression to match, or could you do with splitting right away? `'10.02'.split(/[-/.]/)` will split on the delimiters, giving you an array; you can check that it has a length of 3 or less, then validate each component individually (or join them back together to do the simple `/^\d{1,10}$/.test(parts.join(''))` check).

Comment: I've added example strings. Yes I need a regex to match.

Comment: Are you aware that a date can be in month/day/year, day/month/year, year/month/day... ?

Answer (score 1):

You might use the quantifier `{0,2}` for a non capturing group which would itself match a single one of `[/.-]` followed by 1+ digits 0-9.

To prevent matching more that 10 digits, you could make use of a negative lookahead that would not match 11 digits.

If you want a maximum of 0 - 3, the quantifier can be `{0,3}`

```
^(?!(?:[0-9\/.-]*[0-9]){11}$)[0-9]+(?:[\/.-][0-9]+){0,2}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xP0cjM/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?!(?:[0-9\/.-]*[0-9]){11}$)[0-9]+(?:[\/.-][0-9]+){0,2}$/;

[
  "1",
  "10.02",
  "1111111111",
  "111.111.1111",
  "10.12/2020",
  "/",
  ".10.20",
  "11111111111",
  "111.111.11111"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + pattern.test(s)));
```